# Can't accept invite to become an owner of a Facebook business

Tags: facebook, facebook-business-manager

I set up one of my side project businesses as a Facebook business under a different email than the email attached to my personal Facebook account.

I want my personal Facebook account to own this Facebook business, so everything is under my personal (primary) Facebook account's control.

When inviting my primary Facebook account email to that Facebook business account, I received an email from Facebook to my primary account's email asking to confirm the invitation as expected.

I open the confirmation link in an incognito window, log in to Facebook using my personal Facebook account, pass the 2FA test, and click `accept invite`, but receive the error:

> The content you requested cannot be displayed at the moment. It may be
> temporarily unavailable, the link you clicked on may have expired or
> you may not have permission to view this page.

If I resend the invite, the same error occurs.

Comment: I never solved this problem by getting the invite process to work. I did solve this problem by editing the different email that had ownership of the Business Account and changing it to the email of my personal Facebook account. I then deleted the invite to my personal Facebook account, and now I have what I wanted. Not a general solution, but it might help others.

Comment: You should make that an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never solved this problem by getting the invite process to work.

I solved this problem by editing the different email that had ownership of the Business Account and changing it to the email of my personal Facebook account. I then deleted the invite to my personal Facebook account, and now I have what I wanted.

Not a general solution, but it might help others.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, you can create a business account and that account is able to be attached to different pages etc.. If you have a personal FB account, you can use the same email to create a fb business page.

But a personal page can't take ownership of other pages.

Personal accounts are limited and when you start running ads you can run into limits quickly. For example a pixel owned by a person is limited can partly can't be shared.

As a solution to your problem I would suggest opening a business.facebook.com account and linking the side project to that business account as the manager and admin. It's really just an account with more options.

Comment: `"But a personal page can't take ownership of other pages."`. I am not trying to take ownership of a page with a personal page, but with a personal account. You don't "open" an account on business.facebook.com, you log into it with your personal Facebook account. When I do that I see the Facebook business account for my business, and the FB page that belongs to that FB business account. In the settings for that FB business account I see that the invitation for full control of this account has been sent to the email of my personal FB account, but accepting this invite is the problem in the OP.